# Listen For Program Windows to be Displayed

Tags: vb.net, winapi

The Goal:
I am trying to create a Visual Basic program that will execute some code whenever any new program window is displayed on screen. Just for an easy to understand example: When I launch a program like File Explorer, I want a message box to be displayed when the window for File Explorer is displayed on screen.

The Problem:
Using the code I provided below, my desired outcome works correctly. However, it will also display a message box whenever something like a context menu is displayed as well. I do not want this. I only want a message box to be displayed whenever an actual program window is displayed. I've tried adding checks for checking if the window has 'minimize', 'maximize', and 'close' buttons. But after adding those checks, a message box no longer gets displayed at all, even with a window that has caption buttons, like File Explorer.

This is my code:

```
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As IntPtr
Declare Auto Function SetWinEventHook Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal eventMin As Integer, ByVal eventMax As Integer, ByVal hmodWinEventProc As IntPtr, ByVal lpfnWinEventProc As WinEventDelegate, ByVal idProcess As Integer, ByVal idThread As Integer, ByVal dwflags As Integer) As IntPtr

Declare Auto Function UnhookWinEvent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWinEventHook As IntPtr) As Boolean
Delegate Sub WinEventDelegate(ByVal hWinEventHook As IntPtr, ByVal eventType As Integer, ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal idObject As Integer, ByVal idChild As Integer, ByVal dwEventThread As Integer, ByVal dwmsEventTime As Integer)

Const WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT As Integer = 0
Const EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE As Integer = &H8000

Private hook As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    hook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, IntPtr.Zero, AddressOf WinEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed

    UnhookWinEvent(hook)

End Sub

Private Sub WinEventProc(ByVal hWinEventHook As IntPtr, ByVal eventType As Integer, ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal idObject As Integer, ByVal idChild As Integer, ByVal dwEventThread As Integer, ByVal dwmsEventTime As Integer)

    Dim windowTitle As String = GetWindowText(hwnd)

    If windowTitle <> "" AndAlso IsPopupWindow(hwnd) Then
        msgbox("New Window Detected")
    End If

End Sub

Private Function IsPopupWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As Boolean

    Dim style As Long = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE)
    Return (style And WS_POPUP) = WS_POPUP

End Function

Declare Auto Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer

Private Const GWL_STYLE As Integer = -16
Private Const WS_POPUP As Long = &H80000000

Private Function GetWindowText(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As String

    Dim textLength As Integer = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd) + 1
    Dim text As String = New String(" "c, textLength)

    GetWindowText(hwnd, text, textLength)

    Return text.Trim()

End Function

Declare Auto Function GetWindowText Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Integer) As Integer
Declare Auto Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Integer
```

What approach could I use to better listen for the creation of new program windows? Or, how could I fix my code?

Comment: You could replace everything by subscribing to UI Automation's  `WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent` and verifying that `[AutomationElement].Current.ControlType == ControlType.Window`. A few lines of code, all managed

Comment: Would this allow me to detect when a window is displayed, system-wide, outside of my application?

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of that Automation event. I can post an example, if you care about it. In this case, you should specify what kind of application you have (e.g., Console, WPF, WinForms etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

`EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE` gets triggered for all kinds of objects, not just windows. You will have to retrieve the created object's window class name via [`GetClassName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassname) and ignore whichever classes you don't want to process. Menus have a [standard class name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#system-classes) of `#32768`.

Comment: For my use case, I would actually rather prefer EVENT_OBJECT_CREATED. This is because I want the code I'm trying to execute to execute just before the window is displayed. I only used a message box as an example to help understand what I'm trying to accomplish. The constant I included in my example, 'Const EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE As Integer = &H8000' is specifically listening for a window object. The value &H8000 is a hexadecimal value that represents the number 32768 in decimal.

Comment: @NewedgeIsaiah Windows can be created shown, hidden, shown, hidden etc. So your plan can't work.